# Trying to place the words after word COMPLETE

Tags: google-sheets, regexp-replace

I have the data in the attached sheet where i am trying to placer this line after the word COMPLETE but my formula places the line before the complete. You help towards the problem will be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jd7AVAvHwfznW_tpykhJb58cPvE7BLxtnJCq9fZy0WE/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A9=B2:B9, REGEXREPLACE(A2:A9, "(COMPLETE)", "(No Measure Applicable) $1"), B2:B9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps ?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A9=B2:B9, REGEXREPLACE(A2:A9, "(COMPLETE)",  "$1 (No Measure Applicable)"), B2:B9))
```

Comment: Thank you i did not noticed that $